# How to reference a gameObject inside a prefab? Using GameObject.Find does not work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to use GameObject.Find within a prefab to reference an object that exists in the scene. The name of the object is exactly the same as the actual object.

```
    LoseLives loseLives;
    GameObject loseLivesing;

    private void Awake()
    {
        loseLivesing = GameObject.Find("MasterManager");
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        loseLives = loseLivesing.GetComponent<LoseLives>();
        target = Waypoints.waypoints[0];
      
    }

    loseLives.LoseLife();
```

[Null Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Ok6.png)
I get a null reference when "loseLives.LoseLife();" runs.

Any help with solving the no reference problem would be greatly appreciated!

If you think there is a better way to create the connection between a script on a prefab and a script on a in-scene gameObject could you please explain it or point me to a tutorial, because in all my research I did not have any luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `LoseLives` is a singular, constant object.

#### First Method

Simply making use of the inspector by exposing the fields.

```cs
public class YourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private LoseLives loseLives;

    // ..

    private void Start() {
        loseLives.LoseLife();
    }

    // ..
}
```

[image: Inspector]

It comes with the problem of needing to constantly drag your constant object into the inspector whenever you need it.

For a Prefab, it works if the target object is part of the Prefab, or the Prefab is generated in the same scene as the targeted object.

---

#### Second Method

Using singletons.

**LoseLives.cs**

```cs
public class LoseLives : MonoBehaviour {

    public static LoseLives Instance {
        get => Instance;
    }

    private static LoseLives instance;

    private void Start() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void LoseLife() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**YourScript.cs**

```cs
public class YourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    // ..
    private void Start() {
        LoseLives.Instance.LoseLife();
    }
    // ..
}
```

This works if you have a global, singular instance of `LoseLives` object.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer! I believe these answer do not fit my problem entirely. It is either because I did not explain my issue properly, or because I cannot implement them into my code. I found a work around using static variables and just calling a static variable from the other script into the LoseLives script

Answer (score 0):

Even though it might not be the best approach, I found a workaround for my issue.

I am using a static variable that resides in the other script (CurrencyManager), calling it from the LoseLives script.

Instead of:

```
loseLives.LoseLife();
```

I do:

```
CurrencyManager.playerHealth -= 1;
```

Where CurrencyMananger is the other script and playerHealth is a static variable that is in the CurrencyManager script. This works because a static variable does not require the objects to be referenced in the inspector.

From now on, when I have a problem where I want to reference a gameObject within a script that is on a prefab, I will consider using static variables in my solution.